# С# Помощь по QR гениратору

Tags: c#, qrcode, qr

Нашёл я тут шаблон программы которую хочу поюзать, но не могу сам допилить ибо нету опыта и знаний
как добиться от первого клика копирование в буфер текста из textBox1 и после pictureBox1.Image = qrcode as Image; запихивать то что было в буфере + Сделанную картинку в одну картинку и вывод на печать?.....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string qrtext = textBox1.Text;
QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
Bitmap qrcode = encoder.Encode(qrtext);
pictureBox1.Image = qrcode as Image;
}
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, вы хотите работать с буфером обмена? Если да, то там очень простое апи на уровне get/set https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0

Comment: Не знаю как лучше реализовать с буфером или можно обойтись как то без него
Может вообще проще вывести отельную кнопку которая будет формировать картинку из textbox и pictureBox в отдельную картинку

Comment: Из вашего потока сознания не понятно чего вы хотите добиться. Что вам надо сделать с полученным QR-кодом?

Comment: Полученный QR код нужно объединить с информацией из textbox и выгрузить готовый вариант в формате https://ibb.co/gvfHfJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675067/convert-text-to-image) нашел метод принта текста в картинку. Только учтите что размеры картинки вам нужно будет рассчитывать самостоятельно на основе длинны текста и размеров шрифта:

```
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int height)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        var font = new Font(fontname, fontsize);
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Теперь когда есть картинка из `PictureBox` и способ получить вторую из текста - соединяем "по горизонтали":

```
private Bitmap Merge(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    var res = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width + bmp2.Width, Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(res))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, Point.Empty);
        graphics.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(bmp1.Width, 0));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Теперь, если хотим сохранить объединенную картинку, на какую-нибудь кнопку вешаем такой обработчик (путь задавайте как вам будет удобнее):

```
private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var res1 = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;
    var res2 = ConvertTextToImage(textBox1.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.White, Color.Black, 100, 100);

    string savepath = "image.png";

    Merge(res1, res2).Save(savepath);
}
```

Comment: В первой части при создании квадрата для текста какие именно параметры отвечают за редактирование? Я попытался покрутить  graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)); но не увенчалось успехом.

Comment: В плане "редактирование"?

Comment: Ну да Что бы текст начинался с края ( Уже с применённым bmp2.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone); ) он начинается с середины всей общей картинки.

Comment: Скиньте скрин как это выглядит

Comment: https://ibb.co/wQRJdyj

Comment: В этом случае у вас просто сама картинка с текстом маленькая - она распологается сверху, поэтому и текст будет начинаться примерно с середины. Если вам нужно чтобы он шел вдоль всей грани QR - передавайте `width` в `ConvertTextToImage`, равную грани QR-кода. `height` же подгоняйте исходя из длины текста и шрифта, думаю можно будет примено высчитать количество строк и узнать сколько пикселей нужно на каждую.

Comment: var bmp = new Bitmap(181, 81);

Comment: Окей, а размеры и шрифт текста меняться?

Comment: За это отвечают параметры `fontname` и `font size`. Доступные шрифты можете проверять как тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-enumerate-installed-fonts?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8, но думаю arial какой-нибудь будет везде

Comment: Всё получилось!) Всем спасибо!!!